# How to build a like/dislike function Django Template

Tags: python-3.x, django, templates

I am currently working on a django page that manages books. Different users can enter and rate books. The rating system is an Up/Down (Like/Dislike) button on my Django page. If you press 'up', a user can only vote 'down'. If you press 'down', a user can only vote 'up'. Unfortunately it does not work as expected. If there are more than one up or downvotes, the following happens:
If a user has not yet voted 'up', you can select 'up'. But not 'down'. If I then press 'up' as user, you can only select 'up' again. If I change the user, e.g. testuser1 to testuser2, then as testuser2 I should have different choices like testuser1. But this is not the case.   What can I do?

```
{% comment %} nobody votes{% endcomment %}
{% if that_one_book.get_upvotes_count == 0 and that_one_book.get_downvotes_count == 0%}
<span style="color: darkgreen">{{ upvotes }}</span>
<a href="{% url 'book-vote' that_one_book.id 'up' %}" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_up.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
</a>
<span style="color: crimson">{{ downvotes }}</span>
<a href="{% url 'book-vote' that_one_book.id 'down' %}" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_down.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
</a>
{% endif%}
{% comment %}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------{% endcomment %}

{% comment %} at least one person votes {% endcomment %}
{% if that_one_book.get_upvotes_count >= 1 or that_one_book.get_downvotes_count >= 1%}
{% for post in that_one_book.get_downvotes%}
{% comment %} if user votes down{% endcomment %}
{%if request.user.username == post.myuser.username%}
{% comment %} just see the voting result{% endcomment %}
<span style="color: darkgreen">{{ upvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_up.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
<span style="color: crimson">{{ downvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_down.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
{{ "<!--" }}
{% else %}

{% comment %} only up choice.{% endcomment %}
<span style="color: darkgreen">{{ upvotes }}</span>
<a href="{% url 'book-vote' that_one_book.id 'up' %}" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_up.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
</a>
<span style="color: crimson">{{ downvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_down.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
{{ "<!--" }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% comment %}--------------------------------------------------------------------------------{% endcomment %}
{% for post2 in that_one_book.get_upvotes%}
{% comment %} if you vote up{% endcomment %}
{%if request.user.username == post2.myuser.username%}
{% comment %} just see voting result{% endcomment %}
<span style="color: darkgreen">{{ upvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_up.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
<span style="color: crimson">{{ downvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_down.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
{{ "<!--" }}

{% else %}
{% comment %} only down choice{% endcomment %}
<span style="color: darkgreen">{{ upvotes }}</span>
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_up.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
<span style="color: crimson">{{ downvotes }}</span>
<a href="{% url 'book-vote' that_one_book.id 'down' %}" style="text-decoration: none">
<img src="{% static 'Books/arrow_down.png' %}" height="20" width="20">
</a>
{{ "<!--" }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}


models.py
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pages = models.IntegerField()  # Must call function to take effect
    date_published = models.DateField(blank=True,
                                      default=date.today,
                                      )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                            choices=BOOK_TYPES,
                            )
    myuser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='book_created_by',
                             related_query_name='book_created_by',
                             )
    def check_date_published(self):
        print('----- In Book.check_date_published():', self.date_published, 'vs.', date.today())

        if self.date_published > date.today():
            print('----- Warning: date_published is in the future')
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def get_full_title(self):
        return_string = self.title
        if self.subtitle:  # if subtitle is not empty
            return_string = self.title + ': ' + self.subtitle
        return return_string



    def get_upvotes(self):
        upvotes = Vote.objects.filter(up_or_down='up',
                                      book=self)
        return upvotes

    def get_upvotes_count(self):
        return len(self.get_upvotes())

    def get_downvotes(self):
        downvotes = Vote.objects.filter(up_or_down='down',
                                        book=self)
        return downvotes



    def get_downvotes_count(self):
        return len(self.get_downvotes())



    def vote(self, myuser, up_or_down):
        vote = Vote.objects.create(up_or_down=up_or_down, myuser=myuser, book=self)
        print(self.get_upvotes)





    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' (' + self.author + ')'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.get_full_title() + ' / ' + self.author + ' / ' + self.type

views.py
def book_detail(request, **kwargs):
    book_id = kwargs['pk']
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)

    # Add comment
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.myuser = request.user
        form.instance.book = book
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(book=book)
    context = {'that_one_book': book,
               'comments_for_that_one_book': comments,
               'upvotes': book.get_upvotes_count(),
               'downvotes': book.get_downvotes_count(),
               'comment_form': CommentForm}
    return render(request, 'book-detail.html', context)


def vote(request, pk: str, up_or_down: str):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=int(pk))
    myuser = request.user
    book.vote(myuser, up_or_down)
    return redirect('book-detail', pk=pk)
```

Comment: If required, I also set the view.py or models.py

Comment: On a first look this line:

{% if that_one_book.get_upvotes_count == 0 and that_one_book.get_downvotes_count == 0%}

will hide vote system to all if a book has just one vote.

In django is much better if you try to implement your logic in views.py not in the template. Anyway it will be usefull if you share models.py and views.py

Comment: I updated the code. models.py and the view.py are in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not understand your logic very well.
You can try a simpler approach:

0.- You need to store the votes, so in your Post class add:

```
post_pos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
post_neg = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

1.- You need a place to store data if a user has voted or not. Let's do this:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User

 class UserVote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    vote_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

2.- Now you need a function that handles the logic:

from .models import Post

```
def positive_post(request, post_id):
    #grab the post and the user
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = request.user
    # Now try to find if that user has voted
    try:
        voted = UserVote.objects.get(post=post,user=user)
        # if you can then, user already voted.
        return HttpResponse("YOU ALREADY VOTED")
    except:
        # If u can not, the user didnt vote yet, so 
        # create a new obejct.
        obj = UserVote()
        obj.post = post
        obj.user = user
        obj.vote_type = "positive"
        obj.save()
        # add positive vote to post DB
        post.post_pos += 1
        post.save()
        return redirect("some_place")
```

3.- Make the same function for the negative post

4.- Create a template:

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'blog:positive_post' post.id %}">
      VOTE UP {{ post.post_pos}}
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'blog:negative_post' post.id %}">
      VOTE DOWN {{ post.post_neg}}
  </p>
```

5.- Handle urls.py:

```
 from blog.models import views
   
 urlpatterns = [
     path('<int:post_id>/up/',views.positive_post, name='positive_post'),
     path('<int:post_id>/down/',views.negative_post, name='negative_post'),]
```